# "На фиг" или "нафиг"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Написала в письме отдельно, но мучают сомнения, и в интернете какой -то разброд мнений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, просторечные, точнее жаргонные словечки с трудом поддаются правилам, но думаю, что если рассматривать это как существительное с предлогом, то написание соответствующее. Если это наречие, то тоже раздельно, так как наречия, образованные от существительных с предлогами "без, до, НА, с, под", обычно пишутся раздельно, хотя много исключений из этого правила.

Answer (score 4):

Подобные жаргонные слова лучше вообще не употреблять в речи. Тем более в письменной.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарю — раздельно [link text](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%ED%E0%F4%E8%E3)

Comment: Привет Лопатину!

Answer (score 1):

По всем правилам - "на фиг". Как "к черту". Поскольку никакое тут не наречие, а обычное существительное с предлогом.
Но "нафиг" - это "олбаннский" и своего рода опознавательный знак.

Comment: Еще можно написать  "нафик" - совсем шикарно будет.  

Может, поправите у себя слово опознАвательный?

Comment: Можно и "нафик". Но это не все понимают.